# How can I embed a terminal widget on my desktop?

Tags: software-recommendation, command-line

I use the command line a lot and I would like a widget (possibly integrating itself into the desktop) to provide access to a terminal.

Like this:

- http://www.webupd8.org/2009/05/ubuntu-embed-terminal-into-you-desktop.html

Comment: You mean like a shortcut?  What desktop are you running

Comment: No, i mean something like this http://www.webupd8.org/2009/05/ubuntu-embed-terminal-into-you-desktop.html, something like a real time terminal.Desktop Env ? Gnome/Unity/Default ?!

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you want to give a chance to [**Yakuake**](http://extragear.kde.org/apps/yakuake/) (KDE based, running natively on Gnome), which embeds a drop down terminal emulator at the very top of your screen, and this can be invoked by pressing a custom key (ussually F12).

Yakuake, similar to [**Guake**](http://guake.org/), runs in the background and it's available and ready when you need it in a key press. You can configure if you wish it in the foreground or it can lose focus as a common window.

I personally prefer the usage of Yakuake instead of Guake as I find it fully configurable and easy to set my preferences. It also features "terminal-splitting" on which you can create your custom layout for several terminals running different processes at once, like these shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Additionally, you can have an unlimited number of terminal sessions running at once, each one with its own custom layout.

Good luck!

Comment: This is awesome, thx for the tips guys.

Comment: Where's the repo for Yakuake?

Answer (score 4):

I like [tilda](http://tilda.sourceforge.net/tildaabout.php) a lot. It's a drop-down terminal toggled with a single key shortcut. It is highly customizable, but what I like most about it is that it perfectly blends visually into Ubuntu Desktop.

```
sudo apt-get install tilda
```

[More info here on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilda_%28software%29)

Comment: This works like a charm and is everything I thought it could be plus more. The ability to bind to a keyboard key is fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

Geppettvs mentioned Guake. You might try it if you have trouble with Yakuake

```
sudo apt-get install guake
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a program called Deskterm that does this for you.
https://github.com/jamrizzi/deskterm

Answer (score -1):

I remembee it to be a simple task
Just removing the borders from the terminal window leavi g it sticky.
Im not sure if you can atill doit on gnomeshell but maybe there be a way to doit

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).